# How do i get new line(row wise) output in SQL query using python

Tags: python, mysql, sql, postgresql

I want to output of sql as row wise, dont want output to be inline.

This is the code and output in the image :--

[image: code and output]

So, how can i view my result of a query row wise, not inline.
for eg like this :-

```
   Ursula La Multa        | 4790940
   Rudolf von Treppenwitz | 3593205
   Markoff Chaney         | 2395470
   Anonymous Contributor  | 1197735
```

MOREOVER, HOW CAN I GET RID OF THAT KEYWORD 'DECIMAL' FROM [Decimal('4790940')] AS SHOWN IN OUTPUT

Comment: Don't post code as images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for result in results:
    print ("%s\t | %s" % (result[0], result[1]))
```

Comment: print ("1.%s \n 2.%s \n 3.%s" % (results[0], results[1], results[2]))


THIS IS WHAT I USED THANKS.